# Codeinjector firefox addon triggering Content Security Policy error on twitter

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, code-injection

I am using this firefox addon to run javascript on sites to tweak how they work for me:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/codeinjector

Unfortunately on twitter I get this error:
`Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").`

Is there a way I can override this in firefox settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) is a mechanism which allow a web server to specify, via HTTP headers, which source of content (scripts, images, ...) are considered safe.

As your scripts are not part of the content security policy, they are blocked by the browser, which is the intended behavior.

You can either:

- Use a Firefox plugin, such as [Modify Header Value](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/), to dynamically add your script locations in the CSP rules coming from the HTTP headers.
- Use the same plugin to completely remove the CSP headers. But this is means you will not be protected by CSP when browsing Twitter. This is not safe.
- You can also totally disable CSP rules by disabling `security.csp.enable` in the `about:config` panel, but this is really not safe and I don't recommend it.